# Can temporary data on SSD be moved to HDD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I have a stoarge server setup with 2x 2TB hard drives that are mirrored, but the write speeds are pretty slow.

Is there some way I can setup a much smaller SSD (~120GB) which the data will be initially written to, but when I stop using the server - the data will be offloaded to the hard drives, and deleted from the SSD, in order to get much higher write speeds?

I don't usually move files to it larger than 50GB, and it runs Win Server 2016 if that helps.

Many Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'd suggest to create a custom script for that. You can check the output of `query user`, parse that stream and when there is no other user use `xcopy`. This script should run from `task scheduler` when you want.

Comment: You're talking about data caching, and whether or not you can do this is based entirely on the capabilities of the storage architecture you are using. If that architecture supports write-caching to a separate drive, then what you describe will work.

Comment: @dmb I'm not seeing how that could intercept all incoming writes on a system and redirect them to a cache drive. Are you sure that method works? I assume you're seeing "temporary data" and assuming that means the %usertempdata%, but in reading the body of the question, it appears to me OP is asking that ALL incoming data be written to the faster SSD initially and moved off to slower disks later, rather than just the user's temp data.

Comment: @music2myear Sorry I think I missinterpret what OP wanted. I thought that he would work on a SSD, then when finished(logging out of the server), the task would check if you are there and the moving process would start. For a "dynamic" way this won't work.

Comment: Got it. Yea, for many tech pros the word "temporary" can mean something very specific and the title got me thinking the wrong direction at first too.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/understand-the-cache

Windows Server 2016 has a feature called "Storage Spaces Direct" which has a caching feature.

The link above explains the feature and how it works.

So the answer to your question is "Yes, you can cache data using and SSD in Windows Server 2016 storage environments".